# What happens when we assign 2 values to same variable?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am trying to make a simple assertion which checks if two values are equal. Can someone please explain the behaviour when I assign two different values to the same variable

```
logic src_sig ;
logic dest_sig;
logic alt_sig;

assign a = src_sig;
assign a = alt_sig;
assign b = dest_sig;
```

My assertion sequence is:

```
sequence check_seq(X,Y);
(X == Y);
endsequence
```

And my initial block is:

```
initial begin

#100 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <= 1;
dest_sig <=1;
alt_sig <= 0;
end

#10 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <=1;
dest_sig <=0;
alt_sig <= 0;
end

#10 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <= 0;
dest_sig <= 0;
alt_sig <= 1;
end

#10 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <= 0;
dest_sig <= 1;
alt_sig <= 1;
end

#30 $finish;
end
```

I was expecting that the second assignment will override the first one OR it would be assigned to both `src_sig` and `alt_sig`. So either it should show 2 offences or 4 respectively. But I am getting the following results(3 offences).

```
"testbench.sv", 31: test.check_assert: started at 103ns failed at 103ns
    Offending '(a == b)'
"testbench.sv", 31: test.check_assert: started at 113ns failed at 113ns
    Offending '(a == b)'
"testbench.sv", 31: test.check_assert: started at 133ns failed at 133ns
    Offending '(a == b)'
```

Please explain what is happening here?

EDIT:: Complete code

```
module test_gcc();
logic clk=0; 
logic src_sig,dest_sig,alt_sig;
assign a = src_sig;
assign a = alt_sig;
assign b = dest_sig;
initial begin 
clk = 0;
forever #1 clk=~clk;
end

sequence check_seq(X,Y);
(X == Y);
endsequence
property check_connection(M,N);
@(posedge clk)
($rose(M)||$rose(N)||$fell(M)||$fell(N)) |-> check_seq(M,N);
endproperty
check_assert : assert property (check_connection(a,b));
initial begin

#100 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <= 1;
dest_sig <=1;
alt_sig <= 0;
end
#10 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <=1;
dest_sig <=0;
alt_sig <= 0;
end

#10 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <= 0;
dest_sig <= 0;
alt_sig <= 1;
end
#10 @ (posedge clk) begin
src_sig <= 0;
dest_sig <= 1;
alt_sig <= 1;
end
#30 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: I have some ideas, but without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't go any further. Please create an MCVE.

Comment: I have pasted a link. I can post the entire code too if you need it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your problem lies within code that you did not originally post in your question. This is why an MCVE is so valuable. Please edit your question to include all your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` and `b` are 1-bit `wire`s, because you have not declared them. (In Verilog/SV, unless you specify `default_nettype none` then undeclared objects are `wire`s).

> **If you drive a `wire` from more than one place then a *resolution function* is executed in order to evaluate the value on the `wire`.**

In your case, there are two *drivers* on the `wire a` - the two `assign` statements. The `initial` block ensures that different values are always driven by the two `assign` statements, so the *resolved value* on the wire is always `1'bx`. **The value on `wire a` never changes.**

`wire b` is driven by only one `assign` statement. The `initial` block ensures that it's value changes at 101ns, 111ns and 131ns. **The value on `wire b` does not change at 121ns.**

You have written your `property` so that the *condition* is only checked if there is a change on either `wire a` or `wire b`:

```
  property check_connection(M,N);
    @(posedge clk)
    ($rose(M)||$rose(N)||$fell(M)||$fell(N)) |-> check_seq(M,N);
  endproperty
```

`wire a` never changes and `wire b` doesn't change at 121ns, so the condition is not checked at 121ns.